# “Curriculum Vitae” vs “Curriculum Vitæ”

Tags: latin, typography, ligature

I was just seeing the CV of [Dr. Donald Knuth](http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~uno/vita.html), which he calls as his *Curriculum Vitæ*. So is *Curriculum Vitæ* more appropriate than the commonly used *Curriculum Vitae*?

Comment: I was reading Wikipedia's page - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curriculum_vitae , but I was totally confused and now feel quite philistine. I will pick CV , thanks a lot ;)

Comment: I never saw it written as "æ" and also when I was studying Latin, as far as I can remember, when we were focusing on cases they were written as "ae".

Comment: This is also discussed in the latin stack exchange [here](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/14927/%C3%86-ligature-the-definitive-answer), even though I am not sure if the answers apply to English usage as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Bear in mind that Donald Knuth, as author of Tex, has an above-average fixation with typesetting. I think it’s fair to say that most people would probably not use the ligature, but if you’re in any doubt you could do a quick Google search.

Comment: [I did](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curriculum_vitae#Etymology_and_spellings) and found that one is the plural of the other. Also found that it is common to use the singular form. But couldn't find which is more appropriate.

Comment: I really think you worry too much. Choose whichever you find most esthaetically pleasing and move on to a more interesting problem...!

Comment: @phycker - I believe you've misread that.  *Vitae* and *Vitæ* are equivalent, modulo the typesetting difference.  The plural would be  *vitarum*.

Comment: @Neil - Wouldn't you concur that Learning Latin is an erudite and cerebral endeavor!

Comment: I think *above-average* is an understatement, if you consider that foreign names in the indices of his latest books are given both in Roman letters and also in their correct native alphabets.

Comment: FYI: This is now the first result for a quick Google search on "Vitae or vitæ"

Answer (score 3):

I can’t say which is the “more appropriate”, as that depends on a number of additional factors, with the lion’s share being subjective. That being said, however, I can tell you that the ligature version is the one you would have seen in Rome’s headier days. The digraph version is used simply because most folks do not care to bother with that level of fancy-pants lurnin’ — yes, even while seeking jobs.

EDIT: On re-reading this submission, I realized I sound like I’m implying something I did not intend to. So let me quickly clarify that I meant “learning how to type a ligature”, not that everyone ought to study Latin, or any such related conclusion.